# Page refresh not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, tomcat

I have problem when I try to refresh my page in Firefox using

location.reload(true);

it changes my server URL like my server URL is

> www.mywebsite.com/login.html

so when I refesh my page using location.reload(0) by click on a button. It changes my URL to

> www.mywebsite.com/myproject/login.html

Its only happening on Firefox browser in chrome its working fine.

Also it working fine on my local machine too. Only problem is on live server.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

website is running on apache tomcat server

Comment: What do you get when you `alert(window.location);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why that wouldn't work. Try using:

```
history.go(0)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I just re-read your question. Do you have any odd settings in firefox? Do you have some strange jquery handler bound to the `click` event of that link? Does your site work on Firefox on other machines?

Comment: Normally , I use Chrome browser but today I just check on Firfox. Yes I tested on Mac and Linux machines it not working on Firefox. Is it something with URL rewriting on server.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it on `location.reload()` is enough.
Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/f7tA3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. but the problem was something else as it was jquery error . I put event.preventDefault(); inside the form validation method. I just removed this and its working now.